# Большой расход памяти при обработки Runnable тасков

Tags: java, многопоточность, spring

Есть такой класс:

```
@Component
public class TestClass extends Verify {

    private final ThreadPoolTaskExecutor processExecutor;
    private final BlockingQueue<KPIData> kpiData;

    @Autowired
    public TestClass(
            final DbAddresser dbAddresser,
            final MyDao myDao,
            final ThreadPoolTaskExecutor processExecutor) {
        super(VerificationType.KPI, dbAddresser, myDao);
        this.processExecutor = processExecutor;
        kpiData = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(20);
    }

    @Override
    public void verification() throws Exception {
        startedVerification();
        verifyIndicator.setTitle("tasks");
        final Thread consumerKPI = new Thread(() -> {
            LOG.debug("Consumer thread started....");
            try {
                KPIData kpiData;
                while (!(kpiData = this.kpiData.take()).isLastElement()) {
                    final InconsistsKPICallable callable = new InconsistsKPICallable(((KPIDataImpl) kpiData).getRes());
                    execDispatcher.put(processExecutor.submit(callable));
                    verifyIndicator.incMaxStep();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOG.error("Consumer thread error: ", e);
            }
            LOG.debug("Consumer thread finished....");
        });
        consumerKPI.start();

        try {

            dbAddresser.getKpiAll(kpiData, 5000);

            final Pair<Long, Long> minMaxEntities = dbAddresser::getMinMaxEntities;
            if (minMaxEntities != null) {
                long currentEntityId = minMaxEntities.getLeft();

                while (currentEntityId <= minMaxEntities.getRight()) {
                    if (stopped) {
                        break;
                    }

                    long fromEntityId = currentEntityId;
                    long toEntityId = currentEntityId + 4999;

                    incMaxStep();

                    InconsistsKPIneedUpdateCallable callable = new InconsistsKPIneedUpdateCallable(fromEntityId, toEntityId);
                    execDispatcher.put(processExecutor.submit(callable));
                    currentEntityId = toEntityId + 1;
                }
            }
        } finally {
            consumerKPI.join();
            waitFinished();
            finishedVerification();
        }
    }

    public class InconsistsKPICallable implements Runnable {
        private final List<Pair<Long, String>> kpiList;

        InconsistsKPICallable(final List<Pair<Long, String>> kpiList) {
            this.kpiList = kpiList;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // do hard work with kpiList
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            } finally {
                LOG.debug("InconsistsSmbpKPICallable finished!");
            }
            incCurStep();
        }
    }

    public class InconsistsKPIneedUpdateCallable implements Runnable {
        private final Long fromEntityId;
        private final Long toEntityId;

        InconsistsKPIneedUpdateCallable(final long fromEntityId, final long toEntityId) {
            this.fromEntityId = fromEntityId;
            this.toEntityId = toEntityId;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // do hard work with fromEntityId and toEntityId
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            } finally {
                LOG.debug("InconsistsKPIneedUpdateCallable finished for fromEntityId {} toEntityId {}", fromEntityId, toEntityId);
            }
            incCurStep();
        }
    }
}
```

Вся проблема в том, что вот тут:

```
while (!(kpiData = this.kpiData.take()).isLastElement()) {
      final InconsistsKPICallable callable = new InconsistsKPICallable(((KPIDataImpl) kpiData).getRes());
      execDispatcher.put(processExecutor.submit(callable));
      verifyIndicator.incMaxStep();
}
```

мы очень быстро создаем таски, тем самым забивая всю память. Все из-за того, что `Runnable` таск обрабатываются не так быстро, в отличие от того, как мы их создаем. Я пробовал указать для `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` размер очереди, но тут также упираюсь в то, что мы ее быстро забиваем и получаем исключение: org.springframework.core.task.TaskRejectedException. Подскажите, как можно реорганизовать данный код, чтобы сократить потребление памяти, и не откидывать таски с исключением? Я пробовал искать способы, чтобы если очередь заполнена, вызывающий поток, который добавляет таск просто ждал, а не падал с исключением, но адекватных решений не нашел.

Answer (score 2):

Для тасков с интерфейсом `Runnable` есть исполнитель с очередью заданий `ThreadPoolExecutor` 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html 
 Он принимает параметром очередь заданий `BlockingQueue<Runnable>` и вынимает из нее новые задания по мере выполнения поступивших ранее. Очередь в случае переполнения может не брать задания или блокировать продюсера заданий с помощью метода `offer`.
Вот простой пример на 50 тяжелых заданий, которые выполняются только по 3 одновременно, плюс еще пять помещаются в очередь. Т.о. продюсер не может сразу сгенерировать больше 8 заданий и вынужден ждать выполнения предыдущих и освобождения места в очереди.

```
LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(5);

Thread taskProducer = new Thread(() ->{
    for (int i=1; i<=50; i++){
        final int id = i;
        try {
            workQueue.offer(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("\t\t\t\ttask start " + id);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep((int) (Math.random() * 3000));
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\ttask done " + id);
                }

            }, 20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("task " + id + " added");
    }
});


ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(3, 5, 10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, workQueue);
executor.prestartAllCoreThreads();
taskProducer.start();

while (taskProducer.isAlive()) Thread.sleep(1000);
executor.shutdown();
```

Comment: Вся проблема в том, что использую конфигурацию от spring https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html и не знаю как задать в ней очередь

Comment: сходу за spring трудно сказать, но судя по доку у него есть методы createQueue и setQueueCapacity (т.к. дефолтный размер очереди равен Integer.MAX_VALUE, что при неконтролируемом производстве чревато). Метод createQueue возвращает экземпляр очереди LinkedBlockingQueue, и именно туда стоит добавлять таски используя для продюсера обычную логику работы с такой очередью.